# Find actual position of an element in WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I have a WrapPanel and three buttons on it. the third button in WrapPanel is in second line.
I want to find the real psotion of button4.

```
<WrapPanel Height="100" Width="200">
   <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button2" Width="75" />
   <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button3" Width="75" />
   <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button4" Width="75" />
</WrapPanel>
```

I use this code but it is 0 because margin is 0.

```
int top = button4.Margin.Top //I want in this case top become 23 but it is 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the button position in the `WrapPanel`, you should use `TransformToAncestor` ([msnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
 Point currentPoint = button4.TransformToAncestor(myWrapPanel).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Where `myWrapPanel` is your `WrapPanel`.